Checking admin completion queue is going into infinite loop (NVMe over PCIe)
I'm creating a 64-bit x86-64 kernel and I'm testing it on my real machine. In my nvme driver code, I'm creating the I/O completion queue and calling the `nvme_admin' function at line no. 312 (please see 0).
I'm checking the admin completion queue after submitting the commands to the controller. I'm submitting the commands to the admin submission queue starting from line no. 258 and I'm writing the new tail value at line no. 221. Then I'm checking the completion queue in the call to the function nvme_admin_wait at line 234. Here, the do-while loop at line no. 206 is an infinite loop.
How to identify why the admin entry was never processed? After writing to the doorbell register, processing paused bit (CSTS.PP) is 0. Also the controller is enabled, ready, and fault free (CSTS.CFS). Is there something wrong with the commands I submitted to the nvme controller?
Edit: After fixing the function to get the nvme base address, it is working on qemu but still not on my real machine.
Thanks.

I'd expect to see a TLB flush after changing PDE. More importantly, I'd expect to see some memory barriers in there, e.g. between command fill-in and command submission, and between command submission and status check. On top of that, functions like nvme_init_identify are insane from C language standpoint without at least some volatile in there (see https://godbolt.org/z/5z4eqW94d to find out how C compiler would mangle it).

As Andrey mentioned, anytime you access a h/w register through a pointer, the pointer needs to have volatile on it. (e.g.) val = *((volatile uint32_t *) addr); You can wrap this in a macro or inline function for convenience.

using the volatile keyword doesn't make it work on my real machine. I have corrected the function to get the nvme base address and now its working on qemu. But how to make it work on my real machine? Thanks for the suggestions though.

@AndreyTurkin from my last comment on May 27, could you tell me what else can I try?

Already did, you just ignored it. Memory barriers? You added volatiles... great, now your compiler does sort of what you want. There's also CPU which is free to reorder/split/combine your reads and writes in some wild and amazing order, and MMIO devices cannot live with that (qemu is cpu based emulation so it doesn't see all that). Working with MMIO is kind of hard! Google on how to do it properly. Here's woefully small summary at osdev: https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_mapped_registers_in_C/C++ , and here's a rather mind-bending story on Linux side of things: https://lwn.net/Articles/698014/

Thanks @AndreyTurkin. Earlier, I didn't understand how to use the memory barriers. This time, from the osdev's link that you provided, I added the GCC memory barriers asm volatile ("": : :"memory"); at the locations that you had mentioned earlier. It is still not working :(

I solved this NVMe driver problem. I rewrote the driver from scratch following the wiki and the specification and this commit (please see [0]) finally made it worked.
Thank you so much for the help in the comments above :) I learned a lot along the way.
[0]: https://github.com/robstat7/Raam/commit/eb9bd8c725808d963abd1c87ec2a5e2bcb899d9b
